# getting an error building my app with java 1.6

Tags: java, java-6, java-5

I am looking for help. My web app is running on Websphere 8. It is currently being built with Java 1.5 and compiling fine. However, if I change it to compile with Java 1.6. I am getting the following error. What can I do or change to be able to compile with 1.6? Thank you for any help with this.

```
build-project:
     [echo] myapp: F:\Fire\Fixed\myappweb___MyApp_Application\src\MyApp\build.xml
    [javac] Compiling 175 source files to F:\Fire\Fixed\myapp___MyApp_Application\src\MyApp\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes
    [javac] F:\Fire\Fixed\myapp___MyApp_Application\src\MyApp\src\com\mycompany\myapp\dao\ResultSetWrapper.java:23: com.mycompany.myapp.dao.ResultSetWrapper is not abstract and does not override abstract method updateNClob(java.lang.String,java.io.Reader) in java.sql.ResultSet
    [javac] public class ResultSetWrapper implements ResultSet {
    [javac]        ^
    [javac] Note: F:\Fire\Fixed\myapp___MyApp_Application\src\MyApp\src\com\mycompany\myapp\dao\ResultSetWrapper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 1 error
```

Comment: `myapp.dao.ResultSetWrapper` is not abstract and **does not override** abstract method `updateNClob(java.lang.String,java.io.Reader)` in java.sql.ResultSet - you are implementing ResutSet interface and it has changed in Java 6 that's your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response.What should be my approach to make ResultSet work in Java 6 ?

Comment: You shouldn't create ResultSetWrapper in the first place. To compile with Java 6 you need to implement there all missing methods from the ResultSet interface or remove ResultSetWrapper from your classes.

Comment: by looking at the error it looks like method updateNClob is missing.Any good way to identify if any other methods are missing ?

Comment: Look for `Since: 1.6` in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#updateClob%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Reader%29